# How do i define 2 onClick events in XML

Tags: android, xml, button, sendmail

I have managed to action 1 event in XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/capture_screen_shot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="screenShot"
    android:text="Order"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

How do I add another onClick event "sendMail" for same button in XML?

Comment: You can't. But you can easily call `sendMail` in the `screenShot` method. Or create another event handler method that will call both `sendMail` and `screenShot` (in case `screenShot` is used somewhere else, and you don't want it to always call `sendMail`)

Comment: Thank you. I always want to sendMail. Can you please give me some direction on how to call sendMail in screenShot. PLEASE :)

Comment: `public void screenShot(View v){
    sendMail();
 ....
}` ?

Comment: I have created a new button. (far easier than what @har07 suggest.) Could not get this figured out. Question: Everything is working great. except the attached is shown in app as attached but does not arrive in inbox, only empty mail arrives. WHY?

Comment: Nevermind figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it. How would the button know which onClick event to call? There's only one action that the button knows: a click. Whether that click takes a screenshot or sends an email or both should be handled using logic in your onClick method.

Comment: Please add more detailed explanation to your answer. A code sample wouldn't go amiss.